# Get object from AWS S3 as a stream

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to to figure out whether it is possbile to return some sort of stream (possibly a memory stream?) of an object I get from my AWS S3 bucket.

The S3 bucket contains a lot of different type of images, documents etc. All those should be used on my website. However, I do not want to display the path to my AWS S3 bucket.
That is why I am trying to create a stream and display the images and downloadable documents on the fly rather than with a full path. Does this make sense? :-)

I am using the C#/.NET AWS SDK.

Looking forward to hear about any ideas and directions pointed to!

```
public FileStream GetFile(string keyName)
{
    using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2))
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName
        };

        using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
        using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            // The following outputs the content of my text file:
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            // Do some magic to return content as a stream
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work if you want to hide the path to your bucket http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In .NET 4,  you can use [Stream.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy the content of the ResponseStream (that is a [Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.MD5Stream](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/Util/HashStream.cs#L393)) to a MemoryStream.

```
GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, keyName);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
}

return memoryStream;
```

Where `client.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, keyName)` is an alternative to calling `GetObject` with the request you are creating.

Comment: You may want to edit this to show the `Dispose` of the `ResponseStream`.
AWS docs indicate "In order to use this stream without leaking...please wrap access to the stream within a using block".

Comment: @AaronHudon I read this in the AWS as well, but it is highly unusual for a consumer of an `IDisposable` property to dispose it. This is usually left to the owner of the object. You should dispose the `GetObjectResponse` object by wrapping that in a using block.

Comment: Why copy `response.ResponseStream` and not just use that stream? Why have a second stream? Anyways this answers the question thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Even cheaper way is to use pre-signed URLs to objects in S3. That way you can return expiring URLs to your resources and do not need to do any stream copies. Very low memory is required for that so you can use a very small and cheap VM.

This approach would work for a few resources and only a few clients. With more requests you may hit AWS API limits.

```
using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2))
{
    var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        Verb = HttpVerb.GET, 
        Protocol = Protocol.HTTPS
    };
    var url = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
    // ... and return url from here. 
    // Url is valid only for 10 minutes
    // it can be used only to GET content over HTTPS
    // Any other operation like POST would fail.
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Worked like a charm