# How to avoid storing this file when i move from AWS to Azure DataLake?

Tags: c#, azure, amazon-s3, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I am writing an Azure Function that moves files from AWS S3 to Azure Datalake, I got the download working and I got the upload working but I am struggling to piece the two together because I don't want to store the file in the intermediate app so to say as the azure function itself does not need to store it just pass it on.

Its not so easy to explain so please bear with me a little here while I try explain what I want to do.

When I download from S3 using this code

```
await client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName, Key = entry.Key });
```

I don't have a file system to store it on and I don't want to store it, I want it as some sort of "object" that I can pass directly to the azure data lake writer which looks like this

```
adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.UploadFile(adlsAccountName, source, destination, 1, false, true);
```

The code works fine if I download it to my local disk, and then uploads it, but that's not what I want since the azure function has no storage I want to pass the downloaded object directly to the uploader so to say

How can I achieve this?

**** EDIT ****

```
// Process the response.
                    foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("key = {0} size = {1}", entry.Key.Split('/').Last(), entry.Size);
                        string fileNameOnly = entry.Key.Split('/').Last();

                        //await client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName, Key = entry.Key });
                        GetObjectResponse getObjRespone = await client.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, entry.Key);
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        getObjRespone.ResponseStream.CopyTo(stream);

                        if (entry.Key.Contains("MerchandiseHierarchy") == true)
                        {
                            WriteToAzureDataLake(stream, @"/PIMRAW/MerchandiseHierarchy/" + fileNameOnly);
                        }
                    }
```

and then I pass the memory stream to the azure method but I need a streamuploader, and I cannot fid it, the following complains it cannot convert stream to string

```
adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.UploadFile(adlsAccountName, source, destination, 1, false, true);
```

*** EDIT2 ***

Change the upload method as follows and it creates the file at destination but with 0 size, so I am wondering if I am creating before the download is done?

```
static void WriteToAzureDataLake(MemoryStream inputSource, string inputDestination)
        {

            // 1. Set Synchronization Context
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            // 2. Create credentials to authenticate requests as an Active Directory application
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientCredential).Result;

            // 2. Initialise Data Lake Store File System Client
            adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);

            // 3. Upload a file to the Data Lake Store
            //var source = @"c:\nwsys\source.txt";
            var source = inputSource;

            //var destination = "/PIMRAW/MerchandiseHierarchy/destination.txt";
            var destination = inputDestination;

            //adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.UploadFile(adlsAccountName, source, destination, 1, false, true);
            adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Create(adlsAccountName, destination, source);


            // FINISHED
            Console.WriteLine("6. Finished!");

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading the blob into a MemoryStream and uploading from it? Both S3 and ADLS SDKs support that.

Comment: got ay pointers to documentation or some code snippet? I never worked with MemoryStreams before

Comment: Here is the download part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145696/get-object-from-aws-s3-as-a-stream

Comment: yeah just found that I am looking for the upload part now

Comment: Here is the upload part https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk#create-client-object. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yup it tries now but the file is 0 bytes, so I am wondering if I am trying to upload before it finished download?

Comment: Here is another upload example https://roykim-ca.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/roykim.ca/2016/11/16/using-azure-data-lake-store-net-sdk-to-upload-files/amp/?amp_js_v=a1&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQECAEYAQ%3D%3D#amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Froykim.ca%2F2016%2F11%2F16%2Fusing-azure-data-lake-store-net-sdk-to-upload-files%2F

Comment: `Change the upload method as follows and it creates the file at destination but with 0 size`  @MattDouhan, it seems that you need to set stream position to 0  before write to datalake

Comment: How do I set that to 0?

Comment: `stream.Position = 0;`

Comment: that was the problem, make that an answer I will accept, works like a charm now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change the upload method as follows and it creates the file at destination but with 0 size

It seems that need to set stream position to 0 before write to datalake.

```
stream.Position = 0;
```