# Deserializing string encoded JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to correctly deserialize a JSON string that begins and ends with double quotes?

The data is coming in as a stream (from an AWS S3 object). This is the contents of the stream (note the double quote characters at the beginning and end):

```
"[{\"startTime\":1610396717400,\"eventCode\":44,\"eventParam\":5},{\"startTime\":1610396717700,\"eventCode\":81,\"eventParam\":56},{\"startTime\":1610396717800,\"eventCode\":44,\"eventParam\":4}]"
```

The JsonSerializer does not seem to deserialize this properly. However, for the following contents, it works as expected:

```
[{"startTime":1610396717400,"eventCode":44,"eventParam":5},{"startTime":1610396717700,"eventCode":81,"eventParam":56}]
```

This is the snippet:

```
public class ControllerEventJson
{
    [JsonProperty("startTime")]
    public long StartTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventCode")]
    public int EventCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("eventParam")]
    public int EventParam { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // stream is a MemoryStream
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            // Required for large JSON objects to avoid errors when streaming
            reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Deserialize each object in array individually
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    var obj = serializer.Deserialize<ControllerEventJson>(reader);
                    // Do something with obj
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically deserialize the value as a JSON token, and you'll get a string, which is the JSON array you want to deserialize. (It's been double-encoded, effectively.) Is there any reason you're doing this in a streaming fashion though? It would be rather simpler to read the content with `File.ReadAllText` unless it's genuinely going to be huge.

Comment: What you have is a JSON object, encoded as a JSON string. The answer to your question is "first deserialize the string, then deserialize the result from that", the actual solution to your problem is not having the double serialization to begin with. _Why_ is that string in that format?

Comment: @JonSkeet the data will be coming in as a Stream. I've simplified it to open a file in this example, but the JSON files are stored in AWS S3. And I'm using their API to copy the ResponseStream into a MemoryStream [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165902/17204016).

Comment: @Jungl: If you're already reading the whole thing into memory, it would be simpler to create a `StreamReader` around `response.ResponseStream` and call `ReadToEnd` on that to get the whole JSON as a string.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you, I ended up doing this to get the entire string. Then trimmed the ends for the quotes and used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to get back a List.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.This was tested in Visual Studio and works properly

```
Dictionary<string, string> items = null;
var list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    ...... your code
    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

        Item item = null;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                 items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    continue;

                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    item = new Item();
                    break;

                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    item.Key = reader.Value.ToString();
                    break;

                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    list.Add(items);
                    items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    break;

                case JsonToken.Integer:
                    item.Value = reader.Value.ToString();
                    if (item != null) items.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                    item = new Item();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    var jd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof( List<ControllerEventJson>));
```

result

```
[
  {
    "startTime": 1610396717400,
    "eventCode": 44,
    "eventParam": 5
  },
  {
    "startTime": 1610396717700,
    "eventCode": 81,
    "eventParam": 56
  },
  {
    "startTime": 1610396717800,
    "eventCode": 44,
    "eventParam": 4
  }
]
```

class

```
public class Item
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```